# Can we configure TFS to accept merges only from specific branches?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

We're considering a "functional branch" strategy with DEV, QA, and RELEASE branches. I see how to control check-ins from users, but is it possible to configure the release branch to only accept merges from the QA branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fully restrict a branch to allow merges from specific branches only.

However, you could prevent the check-ins  through a custom [Check-In Policie](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies). You also need to combine it with a **custom path policy** for configuring it to a speficic folder. Detail ways please refer: [How to apply check-in policies to only certain branches or folders](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/girishp/2012/02/16/tfs-2010-how-to-apply-check-in-policies-to-only-certain-branches-or-folders/). As for how to create a custom check-in policy by API, you could take a look at this tutorial: [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)

For a more easier way, you might consider **limiting the security** on those release branches to the person(s) who would be responsible enough to do it right. It's more like an internal process constraint:"*David, please avoid  merging changes other than QA branches, thanks!*"

Comment: Add a check-in policy sample for your reference: [Merge / Branch Only Check in Policy](http://leon.mvps.org/TFS/MergeOnlyPolicy.aspx)